# Merge different rows into one row without losing data - VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, automation, concatenation

I have the following dataset, and I would like to merge different rows in one, without losing data using VBA. I tried different codes, but they only keep the information of the first row.

***What I have right now***
[image: What I have right now]

***What I want to achieve***
[image: What I want to achieve]

If someone could shed some light on that, I would appreciate it
Thanks,
Silvia

That's the code I used:

```
Sub MergeRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim target As String

    'Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

    'Find the last row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through each row (except the first one)
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'Set the target column value
        target = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        'Loop backwards from the current row to the first row
        For j = i To 2 Step -1
            'Check if the target column value is the same as in the current row
            If ws.Cells(j, "G").Value = target Then
                'If the target column value is the same, concatenate the values of the other columns
                ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value & ", " & ws.Cells(j, "C").Value
                ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value & ", " & ws.Cells(j, "D").Value
                'Delete the merged row
                ws.Rows(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

But when I ran it, nothing happened.

Comment: Do you want to merge only the first two rows?

Comment: Always go backwards when deleting rows or mark them for deletion after the loop. While you are going backwards in your j-loop, it'll still screw up the i-loop.

Comment: Your target isn't the same for the rows you're trying to merge so you'll need to figure out a rule on how that's determined. They have "interleukin" in both G-values but how would you decide what to look for?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a data sample **as text which can be copy/pasted** that includes several sets of data.  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sub

```
Sub range_merge()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lastcol
Cells(1, i) = Cells(1, i) & Chr(10) & Cells(2, i)
Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(2, i)).Merge
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you assume OP wanted only first two rows merged? They're using `lastRow` for a reason, I think.

Comment: @Notus_Panda based on the screenshots